# C# SQL: How to initiate code for each distinct value in SQL table column?

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, foreach, dataset

Trying to generate one invoice `foreach` distinct value in my SQL database column.

I have a SQL table, where one of the columns holds names of companies. 9 distinct ones, 20 in total.

Here's an abbreviated example to avoid any confusion:

| ID | CompanyName | Value1 | Value2 | Value3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Company1 | 5 | 3 | 8 |
| 2 | Company2 | 9 | 9 | 1 |
| 3 | Company2 | 4 | 4 | 2 |
| 4 | Company3 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 5 | Company3 | 5 | 9 | 7 |
| 6 | Company3 | 2 | 2 | 1 |

Essentially, what I am trying to do, is bind this table to an `ObservableCollection`, and then create a PDF for each *distinct* company.

So, I am thinking that I need to iterate over the column data, and initiate my method to create PDFs `foreach` distinct value. Please have a look at my code below.

```
try {

    using (SqlConnection con = new(//my connection string))
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new("spMyStoredProcedure", con) { CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure })
    using (SqlDataAdapter da = new(cmd))
    using (DataSet ds = new()) {

        con.Open();
        da.Fill(ds);

        foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows) {

            MyObservableCollection.Add(New MyClass {

                ID = (int)dr[0],
                CompanyName = dr[1].ToString(),
                Value1 = (decimal)dr[2],
                Value2 = (decimal)dr[3],
                Value3 = (decimal)dr[4],
            });
        }

    } catch (Exception ex) {

}
```

There are some holes here.

**I need to understand how to do the following:**

- Where do I call my method to create PDFs? Do I need to wrap the above code in another `foreach`?
- Do I also need to reference the names of my columns `(= "CompanyName")`? How?
- How can I make sure that I only initiate my code for each distinct, unique value?

Comment: Please only one quesion at a time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try doing the following:

```
foreach (var item in MyObservableCollection.Distinct(/*your custom equality comparer if you have one*/))
        {
            //your pdf generating code here
        }
```

For finding distinct records based on a fild, you have two options:

- Write a custom [EqualityComparer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.equalitycomparer-1?view=net-5.0) and pass it as parameter to LINQ's [.Distinct()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinct?view=net-5.0)
- Use LINQ's [.GroupBy()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=net-5.0) as described in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489258/linqs-distinct-on-a-particular-property) and loop with foreach through already sorted list.

After you get all unique items, you can run your code in a loop.